# Rendering 3 different components based on click of buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and need some help on understanding using hooks. I have 3 views I want to render based on 3 different components I want to render based on different TEXT buttons. The buttons would in the same location throughout the components but different text on them!

Component the view will switch from:

```
const Original = () => {
    const [button1, setButton1] = React.useState("button1");
    const [button2, setButton2] = React.useState("button2");
    const testOriginal = () => {};
    const originalView = () => {
        setButton1("buttonview1");
        setButton2("buttonview2");
        return "<div>View 0<button></button><button></button></div>";
    };
    const view2 = () => {
        setButton1("button11view2");
        setButton2("button12view2");
        return "<div>View 2<button></button><button></button></div>";
    };
    const view3 = () => {
        setButton1("button21view3");
        setButton2("button22view3");
        return "<div>View 2<button></button><button></button></div>";
    };
    const ActiveView = () => {
        switch (active) {
            case 1:
                return originalView;
            case 3:
                return view3;
            default:
                return view2;
        }
    };
    return ({
        ActiveView()
    });
};
export default Original;

const View1 = () => {
    return <div>View 1</div>;
};

const View2 = () => {
    return <div>View 2</div>;
};
export default View2;
const View3 = () => {
    return <div>View 3</div>;
};
export default View3;
```

Comment: Can you provide us a valid indented code please ?